# check for existance of directory doesn't fail in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

The below shell script works fine when I give an argument to the script. [ ./test dir_name ]

However, when I don't a give a directory name, the script doesn't fail [ i.e doesn't fall into ERROR message ]. Any reason why the script doesn't fail in that case ?

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "directory name is " $1
if [ ! -d $1 ];  
then
  echo "ERROR: directory doesn't exist"
fi
```

Comment: Quote it: `[ ! -d "$1" ]`

Comment: Or use the Bash construct `[[...]]` - `if [[ -d $1 ]]; `...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't quote `$1` and its expansion is the empty string, your command becomes `[ ! -d ]` after the expansion undergoes word-splitting. You are testing if the string `-d` is non-empty, which it is.

*Always* quote parameter expansions; you'll know when it's not the right thing to do.

```
echo "directory name is $1"

if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
```